# How to intergrate the created view controller into the storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a view controller along with .xib created and also a story board. Now i want to have this viewcontroller's view to appear in the storyboard between the navigation bar and the tableview. I thought of dragging a new view controller and have that class point to the view controller i created.  Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct, drag a view controller from the object pallete, change the class name to your view controllers class name and party on.  Hook up any segues in the story board you need to it.

Comment: Thank you, i just created the controller instance in the viewdidload() and it works.